# Is »hinter« the proper preposition to be used after »Hinterherhecheln«?

Tags: word-choice, preposition

**My main question** refers to the second sentence in the below paragraph from *Der Spiegel* article "[Bundespräsidentenwahl in Österreich. Wiener Schmähungen](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/wahl-des-bundespraesidenten-in-oesterreich-hofer-gegen-van-der-bellen-a-1124067.html)":

> Wie sehr der Wahlkampf die Politik aufgerieben hat, kann man an der christlich-konservativen ÖVP beobachten: Der Riss geht mitten durch diese Partei, deren Spitzenpolitiker teils Hofer, teils Van der Bellen unterstützen. Oder auch an den Sozialdemokraten: Auch wenn die SPÖ sich größtenteils für Van der Bellen ausspricht, wirkt sie wankelmütig - *die einen befürworten einen härteren Kurs in der Flüchtlingspolitik, in der Hoffnung, rechte Wähler zu gewinnen, die anderen sehen darin ein schädliches **Hinterherhecheln hinter** der FPÖ.*

(*Nobert Hofer* ist the candidate for the federal president of Austria nominated by Austrian Freedom Party, FPÖ. *Alexander Van der Bellen* is the former chairman of Austrian Green Party who now candidates as independent candidate. ÖVP is Austrias People Party, a conservative party. SPÖ is Austrias social-democratic party.)

The preposition used in the sentence after *Hinterherhecheln* is *hinter*. According to the [Pons Dictionary](http://en.pons.com/translate?q=Hinterherhecheln&l=deen&in=&lf=de),

> jdm/etw hinterherhecheln = to try to catch up with sb/sth

The translation of *das Hinterherhecheln* should be something like this (I could not find *das Hinterherhecheln* in any dictionary):

das Hinterherhecheln = attempt at catching up

Should not the preposition after *Hinterherhecheln* be *zu* or *mit*? After all, one does *catching up with* someone, not *behind* someone.

**My second question**: Shouldn't *aufgerieben* be *aufgerissen* in the first line of the paragraph? Because the paragraph talks about divisions within political parties, not about the fact that they are worn out by the election campaign.

> [jdn aufreiben = wear down [or out] sb](http://en.pons.com/translate?q=aufrei%C3%9Fen&l=deen&in=&lf=de)
>
> [etw. aufreißen = lacerate sth.](http://www.dict.cc/?s=aufrei%C3%9Fen); [split sth. [Naht]](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/aufrei%C3%9Fen)

** [The Freedom Party of Austria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_Party_of_Austria) (German: Freiheitliche Partei Österreichs, FPÖ) is a right-wing populist political party in Austria.

Comment: »Austrian Green Party candidate for the President of Austria« ist falsch! Alexander Van der Bellen (»VdB«) war zwar lange Zeit der Parteichef der Grünen, aber er wurde nicht von den Grünen nominiert, und er tritt ausdrücklich und mit Nachdruck als parteiunabhängiger Kandidat an. Tatsächlich wird er auch, nachdem für die Stichwahl nur mehr Hofer und VdB übrig geblieben sind, VdB von mehreren Parlamentsparteien und einem parteiübergreifenden Personenkomitee unterstützt.

Comment: Why do you assume that the English preposition should coincide with the German one?

Comment: @c.p. Before reading the below answers, it had seemed that German and English prepositions, in the specific case of "Hinterherhecheln", should be roughly the same, pointing to the act of catching up, or forward moving. I realize that nouns and verbs with the same  meaning in German and English may require different prepositions.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast In the above-mentioned article Alexander Van der Bellen is called "Grünen-Politiker". That's why I assumed he was the Green Party's candidate. Thanks for clarifying how the things actually stand!

Comment: @EugeneStr.: 1. Den Ausdruck »Grünen-Politiker« gibt es in Österreich gar nicht. Entweder spricht man von einem »grünen Politiker« oder von einem »Grün-Politiker«. 2. VdB ist zwar ein grüner Politiker, aber kein »Kandidat der österreichischen Grünen Partei«. 3. Österreich hat keinen »Präsidenten« sondern einen »Bundespräsidenten«. Auf Englisch also kein »president« sondern ein »federal president«. Das verwechselt man besonders in den USA sehr gerne, wo man glaubt, der österreichische Bundespräsident hätte im Land so viel Macht wie der amerikanische Präsident (was eben nicht der Fall ist).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, darf man den Bundeskanzler auch nicht Kanzler (oder chancellor) nennen? Und drückt die Erwähnung des Bundes einen Mangel an Macht aus, oder warum wirfst Du ein, dass Du Amerikaner für uninformiert hältst? Und darf eine deutsche Zeitschrift über Österreich nicht in deutschem Deutsch („Grünen-Politiker“) schreiben? Komm mal runter!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hinterherhecheln* is a compound of *hecheln* and *hinterher*.

> hecheln = to pant
>
> hinterher = behind, after

While the translation

> das Hinterherhecheln = attempt at catching up

is right, it misses some of the meaning. Because the emphasis is on the attempt and on actually catching up. *Hinterherhecheln* implies that, while they are trying to catch up, they really are struggling to not lose even more ground. And despite their trying, they will likely stay behind.

Therefore *hinter* is the right preposition.

---

Also *aufreiben* is correct. Finding a their own position between the two quite polarizing candidates is *wearing out* the other parties.

*Aufreissen* would be wrong because it usually isn't used figuratively.

Comment: siehe auch Bedeutung hier: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hinterherhecheln

Answer (score 4):

The standard alternative to what has been used here would have been

> sehen darin ein schädliches der FPÖ Hinterherhecheln

(from "jmd. hinterherhecheln" and dative). That is correct, but sounds a bit clumsy with the "der" inserted before the substantiation which is needed for the dative. (I do admit "hinter der FPÖ Hinterherhecheln" is no masterpiece of German writing as well, though, because of the duplicated preposition)

Any other preposition than "hinter" is not very well suited for the verb. Normally, it would go without any preposition at all, because it already comes with one.

With regards to your translation: "hinterherhecheln" does implicitly *mean* "trying to catch up with somebody". But it literally *translates* to "running behind someone, heavily breathing" (look up "hecheln" in the dictionary, it's *to pant* like dogs do). So the "hinter" fits very well.

On your second question:

*aufreiben* has quite a number of meanings apart from the technical ("to ream, to broach"):

> Die Kompanie wurde in der Schlacht bei xxx vollkommen aufgerieben

Means they were worn down until defeat in some grinding action, no one left

> Das war eine sehr aufreibende Unterhaltung

means the conversation was emotionally touchy (whatever that emotion was, could be from aggression to pity). "grinding on emotions" would be the undertone here.

And I guess the intended meaning is somewhere in between - The discussion the article is referring to indeed *was* emotional, and it did destroy quite some of the inner structures of the political parties in Austria. IMHO the verb was an ideal choice.